# Switching back and forth in views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

very new to obj-c.

I´ve made a simple MainViewController, loading its view from a xib. (From a standard single view template)

On the main view is a button that takes me to another view. Below is the Method:

```
-(IBAction)forward:(id)sender
{
    tvc = [[TrackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:tvc.view];
}
```

On the other view (also loaded from xib) i have a button to take me back to the main view.

Here is my IBAction for returning to the main view:

```
-(IBAction) back:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However it does not return to the main view. Not with popToRootViewControllerAnimated: either.

Any response will be appreciated!

Comment: this code shouldnt compile because of a `;`

Comment: That was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. It does however compile

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller in your hierarchy? You don't mention one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer applies when you are not using UINavigationBar**

In your Forward button you need to write.

```
TrackViewController *lf = [[TrackViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TrackViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:TVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and in the Backward screen you should right.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load your `MainViewController` in your `AppDelegate` in an `UINavigationController`

```
MainViewController *mainVC = ...
UINavigationController *naviVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
self.window.rootViewController = naviVC;
```

Then you can go forward in your MainViewController:

```
-(IBAction)forward:(id)sender;
{
    tvc = [[TrackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
}
```

and go back in your other ViewController:

```
-(IBAction) back:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you sven, that almost work :) Now when i load the application a blue bar appears in the top of the screen (and stays there in all views) now when i press forward it briefly shows the other page, then slides to an all black view(with the blue bar in the top, and a small "back" button.) When i click this small back button i return to the other view, but nothing happens when i press the back button...

Comment: The blue bar is your navigation bar. It is maintained from the navigation controller you set as root view controller. Could you provide my the complete code so I can figure out what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

If your MainViewController  is inside a UINavigationController, then the `forward` method should look like this:

```
-(IBAction)forward:(id)sender
{
    tvc = [[TrackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:TRUE];
}
```